# Java continue executing loop if exception was throwd

Tags: java, file, exception, try-catch

Example: say I want to open a file. If I get a `FileNotFoundException`, I need to wait for some time and try again. How can I gracefully do that? Or do I need to use nested `try/catch` blocks?

Example :

```
public void openFile() {
    File file = null; 
    try {
        file = new <....>
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `do { ... } while (file == null)` construct.

```
File file = null; 

do {
    try {
        file = new <....>
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Wait for some time.
    }
} while (file == null);

return file;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public File openFile() {
  File file = null; 
  while (file == null) {
    try {
      file = new <....>
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      // Thread.sleep(waitingTime) or what you want to do
    }
  }
  return file;
}
```

Note that this is a somewhat dangerous method, since there is no way to break out unless the file eventually appears. You could add a counter and give up after a certain number of tries, eg:

```
while (file == null) {
  ...
  if (tries++ > MAX_TRIES) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public File openFile() {
    File file = null; 
    while(true){
      try {
          file = new <....>
      } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            //wait for sometime
      }
      if(file!=null){
               break;  
      }
    }
    return file;
 }
```